# What is an adjective for something that is both offensive and funny?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, adjectives

At work we were discussing a topic that ended up being offensive and funny at the same time. As a result of this discussion, we decided we need to know if there is an adjective that would mean the something is both offensive and funny.

Comment: 'Scurrilous' and 'outrageous' are adjectives often applied to comedians; in that context they carry a sense of mischief as well as shock, but not hilarity necessarily.

Comment: @JHCL One definition of scurrilous is "humorously insulting" which is damn close indeed. Post as an answer?

Comment: Actually my sources which refer to specific individuals also have "generally offensive" as alternate meanings, so maybe it can work both ways after all,  I still think off-color is better, see my comment on @EricHauenstein's answer

Comment: What's wrong with tasteless?

Comment: @Joshua Tasteless doesn't indicate humor, sadly.

Comment: @Nakaan: I think the point is that it actually lacks any humor; the person who wants to say the "joke" just thinks it has some, due to bad taste.

Comment: black/gallows humour?

Comment: Offensive *and* funny? I usually call that "funny". =)

Comment: How about "Gottfriedesque"?

Comment: Oh I so badly want to write an answer arguing for "Incredibad"

Comment: "Trump-like" comes to mind.  Of course, with that term you also get "scary" thrown in for free.

Comment: I thought of "Full Metal Jacket", a movie that was full of scenes that made you laugh and feel ashamed of it at the same time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(As suggested following my earlier comment)
[**Scurrilous**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/scurrilous):

> Humorously insulting: *a very funny collection of bawdy and scurrilous writings* (-- Oxford Dictionaries Online)

I think it suggests mischief rather than hilarity, but it may be as close as you'll get.  Humour and Horror aren't natural bedfellows (which is why the combination can be so delicious).

Comment: Scurrilous!  Most excellent.  I wish I had thought of that.

Comment: Scurrilous means insulting to a particular person, though, which often is not the case with offensive humour, eg when it targets a group of people, eg racist, homophobic, sexist etc material.  For example, jokes about Barack Obama could be called scurrilous, but jokes about African Americans *as a group* could not correctly be called scurrilous.

Comment: @Max Williams - you may be right; can you point to a reference for 'insulting to a particular person'?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, sorry.  Do you mean an example of where someone insulted a particular person?

Comment: No sorry, I meant a reference (eg dictionary) for that being the actual definition.

Comment: @Max Willaims I agree with Max Williams as it has [more negative and obscene connotation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scurrilous) than funny and offensive.

Comment: @JHCL: +1 since this is a great word. About "insulting to a particular person," your link to Oxford Dictionaries Online in the answer shows this as the first definition of the word ("Making or spreading scandalous claims about someone with the intention of damaging their reputation").

Answer (score 28):

**Off-Color** is the expression usually used for jokes and humor that has a substantial and generally recognized offensive element. [Link-MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off-color)

**Bawdy** could also work, if the humor is offensive due to sexual content. [Link-MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bawdy)

Comment: Off-color (or off-colour for us brits) is the best option i think.  It nicely conveys the fact that this joke isn't suitable for polite company and that it is likely to cause offense to a large portion of the population.

Comment: Off-color is right up there with Scurrilous in my opinion. It's an excellent second.

Comment: @Nakaan I don't see anything that indicates "funny" element in Merriam-Webster. It might be said after something funny is uttered to mean the joke was a bit offensive, but you cannot mean it was funny by saying it was off-color.

Comment: @Rathony You're right, it doesn't directly mean funny and it's normally used in the context of "off-color joke" so it doesn't quite fit the situation I'm referencing directly. That said, in my experience it's understood that off-color references humor. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @Nakaan Yep! I am pretty sure nobody will take "off-color" as funny unless uttered with a joke. But "hillariously offensive" does. The thing is one adjective is not enough. It applys to Risque, too.

Comment: I think this may be a case where the predominant use of an adjective colors it's meaning, since off-color is typically, but not exclusively, used to describe humor.

Comment: It's a small leap since "off-color" does not by definition mean funny as well as improper but it is a generally understood expression used with extreme regularity among native speakers when referring to comedy routines or jokes.  Sorry to disagree @Rathony but "Off-color" is main stream where "hilariously offensive" is not.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I am not sure how you define "mainstream" without a reference, but this contributor of Forbes Magazine did use ["hilariously offensive"](http://www.forbes.com/sites#/sites/markhughes/2015/03/27/review-get-hard-is-hilariously-offensive-with-a-point/) about a "pretty offensive" movie. I think he meant "very funny" and "offensive" at the same time. Why would he not use *off-coror* if it is such a mainstream as you claim? Maybe, Forbes' editor is not in the mainstream.

Comment: Mainstream doesn't mean the same thing as "exclusive", though here's the NGRAM chart comparing use of "off-color"  vs. "hilariously offensive": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=off-color%2C+hilariously+offensive&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coff%20-%20color%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @KristinaLopez Sorry, but I can't agree with you saying that "off-color" is a mainstream word which means the same as "hillariously offensive" even though it has more hits in the Ngram. Probably they were used under different circumstances. I wish I had time to separate those "*off-color*" used under different circumstances, but I don't. Also, I don't trust Ngram because such a short word can be used in *completely different* situations.

Comment: @Rathony, there's nothing wrong with your answer.  It's just not the one that gets used the most often to describe OP's request, IMO.  It's a phrase but not what I'd consider the "go to" phrase to most succinctly describe something that's naughty or offensive, if you will, and also funny.  My vote is for "off-color".

Comment: @KristinaLopez I understand. Good day.

Answer (score 10):

*Ribald* seems to fit.

> referring to sexual matters in an amusingly rude or irreverent way.

Answer (score 9):

Consider,

***risqué***

> verging on impropriety or indecency: off-color : risqué jokes
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/risqu%C3%A9)

***racy***

> Slightly improper or indelicate; suggestive; risqué : *a racy joke*
>
> [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/racy)

***blue***

> Off-color, risqué : *blue jokes*
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blue)

Comment: Note that *racy* may be confused with *race-y*, meaning racist, especially if spoken

Comment: These are fairly specific to material that is  *sexually* improper or indecent.  If the joke is offensive for some other reason, *risqué* or *racy* would not apply so well.

Comment: Neither of those would apply to dead-baby comedy, which is generally considered both offensive and funny.

Comment: @Mark Dead-baby comedy would be a form of black comedy.

Answer (score 9):

I can come up with **"coarse humor"**

> - [coarse](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coarse) - rude or offensive
>
> "She found the **coarse humor** of her coworkers offensive."

or

**"grossly comic"** means that in addition to being funny, something is also rude and offensive.

e.g.

Did you find the play funny ?

Yes, funny, **grossly funny**.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure there's a exact match for this but **outrageous** has the correct connotations --it has a literal sense of offensive, but is often used in reference to things that are funny ("outrageously funny").

> shockingly bad or excessive.
>    wildly exaggerated or improbable.
>       very bold, unusual, and startling.
>   https://www.google.com/webhp?q=outrageous

Answer (score 2):

"Offunsive"  - because it's fun and offensive.

(okay so it's not a real word, so what? how do you think new words get made?)

Comment: My coworkers and I like this answer. If it were real it would be the accepted answer. Take your +1 and spend it wisely.

Answer (score 2):

The word *edgy* seems to fit this description fairly well from my own observations of how others have used it, although I think that may be a a result of a seemingly recent shift of the usage of the word rather than it's original intent.

Answer (score 1):

[*Hilariously offensive*](http://www.forbes.com/sites#/sites/markhughes/2015/03/27/review-get-hard-is-hilariously-offensive-with-a-point/) describes something offensive and funny at the same time. You can visit the Forbes Magazine link to see what it means.

When you google it, you will find a lot of hits that show how some pictures and words are hilariously offensive.

[*Hilarious*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hilarious) means "very funny" and it is broadly used by U.S. comedians and media because of its pronunciation.

I don't think one adjective is enough to express it.

Answer (score -2):

*Sarcastic*: using or showing sarcasm.

> Definition of sarcasm:
>
> - sharp and often satirical or ironic utterance designed to cut or give pain
> - a mode of satirical wit depending for its effect on bitter, caustic, and often ironic language that is usually directed against an
>   individual, e.g. *an offensive weapon*.

Also *derisive* (characterized by or expressing derision; ridiculing; mocking)

> Use the adjective derisive to describe something or someone that
> mocks, expresses contempt, or ridicules. You may sometimes catch your
> kids making derisive comments — especially if you ask them to do
> chores instead of whatever they think is more important. *Source*:
> [vocabulary.com](http://vocabulary.com/dictionary/derisive)

*EDIT1* (to respond to a comment stating that *sarcasm* isn't offensive):

The above definition of "sarcasm" indicates that it is "usually directed against an individual", whilst offensive is defined as "characterized by attack; aggressive".

*EDIT2* (to respond to a comment stating that *derisive* cannot be funny):

"Derision" definition by MW:

- the use of ridicule or scorn to show contempt;
- a state of being laughed at or ridiculed: a state of being derided.

"Ridicule" definition by MW: the act of making fun of someone or something in a cruel or harsh way; harsh comments made by people who are laughing at someone or something.

Comment: Sarcasm isn't offensive that I've ever heard (ignoring edge case of a sensitive person) and derisive isn't funny (again ignoring certain edge cases).

Comment: @Nakaan: Do you have the sense of humour? Do you think that "funny" and "humoristic" are not related? - *Extract of Cambridge dictionary:  a sarcasm is used to ​criticize something in a ​humorous way. For example "You have been ​working hard," he said with ​heavy sarcasm, as he ​looked at the ​empty ​page. Extract of Wikipedia (Humour): Most people are able to experience humour—be amused, smile or laugh at something funny—and thus are considered to have a sense of humour*.